# Cmd файл для вывода в файл

Tags: cmd

Здравствуйте! помогите пожалуйста  в cmd разработать файл для вывода в файл списка всех вложенных директорий заданного каталога (директория задается произвольно при запуске файла)

Answer (score 1):

[оно?](http://www.cyberforum.ru/cmd-bat/thread1061998.html)

Comment: нет,полностью,с  чего начать?

Comment: создаете текстовый файл,пишете в него:
    @dir "c:\" /b /s /ad>file.txt  
либо что-то другое вместо c:\, изменяете расширение файла на .bat, запускаете и рядом с ним создастся файл file.txt со всеми дирректориями

Comment: простите за назойливость,у  меня создается  файл,но он пустой,это так  надо?

Comment: а директорию правильно написали? откуда запускаете? попробуйте с правами администратора

Comment: ДА да,@dir "%~1" /b /s /ad>file.txt, все  равно пустой файл открывается

Comment: @rej, не рядом, а в текущем каталоге, ибо если я запущу батник как c:\temp\getfolders.cmd, то файл создастся в корне c:, если он был текущим каталогом.
@iamcrisbrown, а вы уверены, что указанный каталог содержит другие каталоги? :-) (так, на всякий случай, а то мало ли :-))

Comment: попробуйте так:

    @dir "c:\" /b /s /ad>file.txt

 если пишете "%~1" вместо "c:\", то нужно запускать батник из командной строки с параметром директории. пуск-выполнить-cmd.
переходите в каталог с созданным батником, для этого вводите
 
    D: 

 (если файл лежит не на диске C, т.е. имя диска), 

    cd temp\new

 (если файл лежит в папке new, которая в папке temp). и вводите полное название батника, пробел, директория для анализа в кавычках:
    
     mybat.bat "c:\"

Answer (score 0):

Как вам уже подсказали, просто это сделать с командой

```
dir /b /s /ad
```

---

Чуть сложнее, но более гибко:

```
@echo off
set fname=%~1
:: Здесь получаем параметр к батнику (полный путь до каталога)

:: если каталог существует, то начинаем перебирать вложенные каталоги, иначе сообщим о его отсутствии и вернем код ошибки 1
:: подробнее в справке for /?
if EXIST "%fname%" (
    for /R "%fname%" %%F in (.) DO (
        echo %%F >> folders.txt
    )
) else (
    echo Каталог не существует
    exit 1
)
```

- %%F двойной процент не просто так.
- Имя выходного файла можно задать в начале через переменные среды, также как поступаю с параметром.
- Если писать echo %%F >> CON то вывод будет в консоль, аналогично echo %%F
- Двойной знак больше означает дописывание в файл
- В качестве имени каталога сейчас выводится полный путь, но можно писать все что угодно, подробнее в for /?

  ~dpF       - переменная F раскрывается в имя диска и путь
  ~nxF       - переменная F раскрывается в имя файла и его расширение
  ~fsF        - переменная F раскрывается в полный путь с короткими именами

Экспериментируйте.